# Changing the file name of a tmp file uploaded through a form

Tags: php, variables, file-io

Like the title say I want to change the file name of the file a user uploads through a form. here are codes

**HTML**

```
    <form action="editprofile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <p>Upload your image:<p /><input type="file" name="myfile"></p><br />
         <p><input type="radio" name="type" value="defaultDot">Use Default</p>
         <p><input type="submit" name="updateAvatar"></p>
    </form>
```

and here is my php script that moves the uploaded file to the correct directory
**PHP**

```
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
    if($name){
        //start upload process
        if($size != FALSE){
            $location = "images/avatars/$name";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$location' WHERE id=$id");
            $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=aqua face=Tahoma>Avatar Updated - Uploaded Image!.</font></p>';
        }else{
            $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=red face=Tahoma>Please only submit image files!</font></p>';
        }
    }
```

How would I be able to give the image a custom name? for instance I have a variable called **$username** which stores a session variable of the user's name. What if I wanted to name the image to the **$username** variable with the same file extension?

**EDIT:EDIT:EDIT:**
Added your if statement lawrence and I swapped the vars in move_upload_files and it still does not work...
**Code**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($username) && is_numeric($id)
&& isset($_FILES['myfile']['error']) && $_FILES['myfile']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_OK'){
if($_POST['type'] != "defaultDot"){
    //$avaURL = $_POST['url'];
    //$updateURL = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$avaURL' WHERE id=$id");
    //$avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=aqua face=Tahoma>Avatar Uploaded!</font></p>';
    $name    = basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    $ext     = end(explode('.', $name));
    $move_to = "images/avatars/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_',$username).'.'.$ext;
    $info    = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);

    if($name){
        //start upload process
            $allowed = array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif');
            if($info[0]>0 && $info[1] > 0 && in_array($info['mime'],$allowed)){
                if($info[0]>200 || $info[1] > 200){
                    //File dimensions too large
                    $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=red face=Tahoma>File dimensions too large.</font></p>';
                }else{
                    //File put contents will over write if file exsist
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $move_to);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users
                                SET avatar='".mysql_real_escape_string($move_to)."' 
                                WHERE id=".$id." AND owner='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
                    $avaMessage = 'Avatar Updated - Uploaded Image!.';
                }
            }else{
                $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=red face=Tahoma>Please only submit image files!</font></p>';
            }   
    }else{
        $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=red face=Tahoma>Please select a file!</font></p>';
    }

}else{
$avaURL = 'images/avatars/default.png';
$updateURL = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$avaURL' WHERE id=$id");
$avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=aqua face=Tahoma>Avatar Updated - Default.</font></p>';
}
}
```

Still not working even with the fixed 'POST' Lawrence...

Comment: can't you just call move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location\$username)

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($move_to,$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
` thos vars need swapping round

Comment: @ThatBenderGuy you need to add the first if statement like mine

Comment: whats this line `if(!$_POST['type'] == "defaultDot"){
` that should be `if($_POST['type'] != "defaultDot"){`

Comment: I fixed the `if(!$_POST['type'] == "defaultDot"){` and it's still not working, It's the first IF statement because IMMEDIATELY after the first if statement I have an echo and it's not echoing so it's the first if statement

Comment: It looks as if it should work, try debugging it abit by print_r($username) and print_r($id) it works for me if I set thos vars, id needs tobe a number. how are you assigning them?

Comment: strange, I printed them and they do show vars assigned to them...

Comment: I don't know what it is because I temporarly changed the if statement back to `isset($_POST['updateAvatar'))` and I get the **Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainwebsite\editprofile.php on line 83** error.

Comment: yeah coz it set when the form is posted but its as if the $_FILES array is not getting populated or your getting an error, try print_r($_FILES) and see if there's an error other then UPLOAD_ERR_OK, also try error_reporting(E_ALL) also echo the ` $avaMessage ` at the bottom perhaps that will narrow it down on where its failing.

Comment: I actually used `echo $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];` and it's returning nothing. this is what I get if i **print_r($_FILES)** ----------------- `Array ( [myfile] => Array ( [name] => objection-vector.png [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 ) ) `

Comment: that means `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` how big is the file, increase the `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024" />` to a larger value, like to 1048576, (my bad)

Comment: Success! It works! now what would the if statement look like to check for the file size? would it look like this? `if($_FILES['myfile']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE'){ //too large file size }`?

Comment: great stuff, yeah it would exactly look like that, put that above the first if statement, perhaps I should of added that lol

Comment: ok. Now the only problem I have is that it is not updating the database with the new location of the users avatar.

Comment: I added `owner` column in the query you can probably remove that if your setting the $username & $id from a session, originally I thought you were passing the values through POST, if `$id` is not a secure var then a user could change the image for anyone

Comment: ok fixed that and everything is working fine! ONE last question though (sorry) but my if statement `if($_FILES['myfile']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE'){ //too large file size }` doesn't seem to work. and yes it is before the other if statement. any ideas?

Comment: you can try `if($_FILES['myfile']['error']==2){ //too large file size }` make sure the image is over the specified limit, 1048576 is 1mb in bytes

Comment: ok that one worked =) thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a secure & safe way todo it, a post request needs checking, just checking `$name` is not enough, `$username` needs any special chars stripped, `$id` needs checking its set and is numeric, file specific type extension needs finding, also allowed mime types need cross matching, plus width and height sizes need checking, lots to think about, uploads can be extremely insecure, not to mention images can have php injected into the file comments and if not handled correctly may get executed:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($username) && is_numeric($id)
&& isset($_FILES['myfile']['error']) && $_FILES['myfile']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_OK'){

    $name    = basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    $ext     = end(explode('.', $name));
    $move_to = "images/avatars/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_',$username).'.'.$ext;
    $info    = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);

    //not more then 200px
    if($info[0]>200 || $info[1] > 200){
        //file too large
    }

    $allowed = array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif');
    if($info[0]>0 && $info[1] > 0 && in_array($info['mime'],$allowed)){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],$move_to);
        mysql_query("UPDATE users
                     SET avatar='".mysql_real_escape_string($move_to)."' 
                     WHERE id=".$id." AND owner='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        $avaMessage = 'Avatar Updated - Uploaded Image!.';
    }else{
        //Not allowed
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <!--1 MB = 1048576 bytes-->
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />

     <p>Upload your image:<p /><input type="file" name="myfile"></p><br />
     <p><input type="radio" name="type" value="defaultDot">Use Default</p>
     <p><input type="submit" name="updateAvatar"></p>
</form>
```

---

**UPDATE EDIT**
Here is an OOP version of the upload process, perhaps you will find it interesting, I added all possible errors too ;p

```
<?php 
Class updateUserAvatar{
    public $upload_path;
    public $full_path;
    public $name;
    public $size;
    public $ext;
    public $output;
    public $input;
    public $prefix;
    private $allowed;

    function upload(){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            if(isset($_FILES[$this->input]['error'])){
                if($_FILES[$this->input]['error'] == 0){
                    $this->name      = basename($_FILES[$this->input]['name']);
                    $file_p          = explode('.', $this->name);
                    $this->ext       = end($file_p);
                    $this->full_path = rtrim($this->upload_path,'/').'/'.preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $this->prefix).'.'.$this->ext;
                    $info            = getimagesize($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name']);
                    $this->size      = filesize($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name']);

                    if($info[0]>$this->allowed['dimensions']['width'] || $info[1] > $this->allowed['dimensions']['height']){
                        $this->output = 'File dimensions too large!';
                    }else{
                        if($info[0] > 0 && $info[1] > 0 && in_array($info['mime'],$this->allowed['types'])){
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$this->input]['tmp_name'],$this->full_path);
                            $this->output = 'Upload success!';
                        }else{
                            $this->output = 'File not supported!';
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==1){$this->output = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==2){$this->output = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in our HTML form!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==3){$this->output = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==4){$this->output = 'No file was uploaded!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==6){$this->output = 'Missing a temporary folder!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==7){$this->output = 'Failed to write uploaded file to disk!';}
                    if($_FILES[$this->input]['error']==8){$this->output = 'A PHP extension stopped the file upload!';}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function setPath($var){
        $this->upload_path = $var;
    }
    function setAllowed($var=array()){
        $this->allowed = $var;
    }
    function setFilePrefix($var){
        $this->prefix = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $var);
    }
    function setFormInput($var){
        $this->input = $var;
    }
}//END CLASS


if($_POST['type'] != "defaultDot"){
    //Setup
    $upload = new updateUserAvatar();
    $upload->setPath('./images/avatars/');
    $upload->setFilePrefix($username);
    $upload->setAllowed(array('dimensions'=>array('width'=>200,'height'=>200),
                              'types'=>array('image/png','image/jpg','image/gif')));
    $upload->setFormInput('myfile');
    $upload->upload();

    if($upload->output == 'Upload success!'){
        //do query
        $updateURL = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$upload->full_path' WHERE id=$id");
    }
    //message
    $avaMessage = $upload->output;
}else{
    $avaURL = 'images/avatars/default.png';
    $updateURL = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET avatar='$avaURL' WHERE id=$id");
    $avaMessage = '<p><font size=2 color=aqua face=Tahoma>Avatar Updated - Default.</font></p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: only problem with this code is I get this warning **Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\mainwebsite\editprofile.php on line 83** -- 
  --
**Code on line 83**  
`$info    = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: Check that `$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` is set. it would not even get to that function if it was empty so you must not used all the code including the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

Comment: I'll edit the main question to show you what I have. I ommited some and kept some original code to make it work. I have several forms on my page so that's why `isset($_POST['updateAvatar'])` is there

Comment: ok I don't get any errors now but now it is completely nonfunctional. ugh. This is becoming a headache lol

Comment: there was a space in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST '`, its the formatting on SO, it should work perfect now ;p make sure $username and $id is set.

Comment: changed it and it still won't work lol and $username and $id are set. It is sadly still not working /:

Comment: @ThatBenderGuy lol this is classic, you are now using the code with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST '` error... use the code I have in my updated answer, were get there eventually

Comment: in your code change `!$_POST['type'] == "defaultDot"` to `$_POST['type'] != "defaultDot"`

Comment: Done, still not working. It's the first IF statement because IMMEDIATELY after the first if statement I have an echo and it's not echoing so it's the first if statement

Answer (score 1):

I think http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php will do what you need. parse the $location and rebuild it, replacing the basename field with your $username.