# echo file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] doesn't do anything

Tags: php

I have written the following code. Nothing is written in the web browser and no error is thrown. Can anyone please help me to identify the problem?

```
try {
   echo file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Here is the form:

```
echo "<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
        <p><input type='file' name='myfile'/></p>
        <p><input type='submit' value='Upload'/></p>
        </form>";
```

The thing was that I was following a tutorial where I was supposed to set: $image=file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]); When the person in the tutorial tried to echo it the files content was written in the browser. Nothing happened for me. I assume it is not working.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_FILES);` return if you put it right after `try {` block?

Comment: Show your html.  Did you include an `enctype` in your form?

Comment: If I ise var_dump($_FILES); I get the following:  array(1) { ["myfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(23) "2013-07-25 07.06.59.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpHIh8Nm" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(499775) } } Din fil har nu laddats upp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**use**

```
  file_get_contents($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]);
```

**instead of**

```
  file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
```

**`since <input type='file' name='myfile'/>`**

better ref from [Changing the file name of a tmp file uploaded through a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266259/changing-the-file-name-of-a-tmp-file-uploaded-through-a-form)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($username) && is_numeric($id)
&& isset($_FILES['myfile']['error']) && $_FILES['myfile']['error']=='UPLOAD_ERR_OK')
{
    $name    = basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
    $ext     = end(explode('.', $name));
    $info    = getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);

}
```

Comment: The thing was that I was following a tutorial where I was supposed to set: $image=file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]); When the person in the tutorial tried to echo it the files content was written in the browser. Nothing happened for me. I assume it is not working.