# how to print image inside table of html through file_get_content?

Tags: php, image, file, email

I am preparing the email body in such a way customer signature should be printed in a cell

```
$message_body .=    '</p>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 418.542px;"><strong>Signature:</strong></td>
                                    <td style="width: 156.875px;">';
                                    try {
                                           echo file_get_contents($_FILES["signature_image"]["tmp_name"]);
                                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                                            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                                        }
                $message_body .=   '</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>';
```

but it does not do anything and the cell in an email remains blank. whereas, when I hit this PHP function from postman it does print image in the body of the response.

[image: email body]

---

### Postman Response

[image: postman response]

note: I am posting this question after checking these posts already:
[echo file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675353/echo-file-get-contents-filesimagetmp-name-doesnt-do-anything)
and
[Is a file in $_FILES the same as a file_get_contents when referring to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161401/is-a-file-in-files-the-same-as-a-file-get-contents-when-referring-to-an-image)

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For emails, you have to provide an `img` html element linked to a file that is accessible on the web, or use embedding with a file attachment, boundries, and content types. You cannot simply echo the binary of a file into the middle of an email like that.

Comment: If you are sending an email any links/images need to be referenced by the full URL, local directory navigation won't work. <img src='https://example.com/images/$customer_signature.jpg'> something like that will work, try assigning the image to a variable.

Comment: actually, i am confused, because the image coming in $_files through http post.it is not stored on the server yet.how can i use a complete path when it is not stored on disk yet.

Comment: You need to store the image on your server, I would advise creating a table with references to the image file names along with dates and customer id etc. Then reference the full url of the image on your server in the email using an image tag.

Comment: yes, I know the procedure, I thought maybe a direct assignment should save me from a database call. thanks for the help.